# WCF - Creating multiple service instance for a single client based on tag/conditionally (not based on percall)

Tags: wcf-client

I see WCF provides persession/percall/single instance modes and single/multiple/reentrant concurency model.

Currently I am using persession instance mode and multiple concurency mode for my service which creates one instance/service object for each client and serves on multiple threads requests from clients.

But actually I want to achive this:

I want to create multiple instances of service objects (not for each call like PerCall, but based on tag: for ex say guid) and I want the service to be re-entrant. Is it possible?

thank u for ur suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).